# Trouble tracking Android view changes

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm new to Android and have done pretty well so far in making my first app. Thanks to everyone making this site a great resource.

In my app I am passing data in a bundle to rebuild a fragment when the orientation of the screen changes. When this happens I am rebuilding rows in a table layout that include a spinner, an edittext, and another spinner. When the fragment finishes loading, all of the rows contain the information from the last row prior to the orientation change. For example:

b4 orientation change:

a      b      c

d      e      f

g      h      i

after orientation change:

g      h      i

g      h      i

g      h      i

From tracking the views in the debug tool when I rotate the screen I have found that the values are passed correctly and that the values are set in the new rows correctly in the onActivityCreated method. After this the onStart and onResume methods run without changing the values. Then at some point between onResume() and when the fragment loads these values change. I figured this out by attaching an onItemSelectedListener to the spinners and tracking when it was called. My understanding of the fragment lifcycle is that there are no other methods that are called after on Resume, so I am very perplexed.

What is going wrong? Is there another lifecycle method that is called after onResume? Is there a way of tracking what is passing the wrong values to the views?

Any help is appreciated.

T

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was happening but this was solved by moving the code that set the values of the spinners and edittext views to the onResume call.